# PHP: Is ReflectionClass future-compatible?

Tags: php

I have been using the cool reflection class in my framework. I wonder whether or not ReflectionClass is future-compatible? For example, in PHP5.3 or PHP6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes that are bundled with PHP don't tend to just "disappear" ; especially classes that have been added only "lately" -- the Reflection API has only been added in PHP 5.

For PHP 5.3, it is still here *(classes like that don't go away in a minor version)* ; and, in fact, it is being improved with PHP 5.3.2 -- there is a new method, from what I've heard.

For PHP 6... Well, always in motion the futur is, as one would say... But I'd bet the reflection API will stay : it is really useful, is a great addition to the language, and is used by several modern tools.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, go4it!

Reflection is quite new and used in many big frameworks like Zend Framework or Doctrine ORM.